# What's the opposite of "embarrassingly parallel"?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, terminology, parallel-processing, multicore

According to Wikipedia, an "embarrassingly parallel" problem is one for which little or no effort is required to separate the problem into a number of parallel tasks. Raytracing is often cited as an example because each ray can, in principle, be processed in parallel.

Obviously, some problems are much harder to parallelize. Some may even be impossible. I'm wondering what terms are used and what the standard examples are for these harder cases.

Can I propose "Annoyingly Sequential" as a possible name?

Comment: If "embarrassingly parallel" means that it is really easy to see how to parallelise it, then the opposite could be that (a) it seems that it _ought to be_ parallelisable, but in practice it turns out to be _very hard_ to do so, or (b) it's _easy_ to see that it _can't_ be parallelised. The respective terms could be (a) "embarrassingly parallel of the second kind" and (b) "respectably non-parallel".

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Inherently sequential**.

Example: The number of women will not reduce the length of pregnancy.

Comment: Good name. Is that your invention, or the commonly accepted term? Also, nice example, but I'd still like a good example from the domain of computer software. The best I can think of is parsing C code, but that's complex enough that some parts can probably be parallelized.

Comment: I made it up, but I seriously doubt that I coined a term here. 

There are many examples of sequential work flows, e.g. you can't really fire an employee before hiring the person, you can't (or at least should not) ship an order before the customer places the order and so forth.

Comment: Yes, but N women can have N babies in the same amount of time as one woman can have anywhere from one to eight babies.

Comment: Yes, "inherently sequential" has been used for a while now by complexity theorists studying parallel computation classes like NC.

Comment: Forget women.  Lets just get a fleet of protein depositing robots, if each robot only has to put a couple cells together, we could definitely have that baby in less than 9mo.

Comment: I think this is wrong.  I believe the accompanying phrase is "disconcertingly serial".  Inherently is not the appropriate opposite of embarrassingly.

Comment: @Blank: so “disconcerting” is an opposite to “embarrassing”? That said, I’ve seen “inherently sequential” in a lot of places and I believe it’s the most commonly-used idiom. It also *describes* the fact nicely, since this serialism *is* inherent in these algorithms.

Answer (score 27):

There's more than one opposite of an "embarrassingly parallel" problem.

### Perfectly sequential

One opposite is a **non-parallelizable** problem, that is, a problem for which no [speedup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) may be achieved by utilizing more than one processor.  Several suggestions were already posted, but I'd propose yet another name: a **perfectly sequential** problem.

Examples: [I/O-bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound) problems, "calculate f<sup>1000000</sup>(x<sub>0</sub>)" type of problems, calculating certain [cryptographic hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).

### Communication-intensive

Another opposite is a parallelizable problem which requires a lot of parallel communication (a **communication-intensive** problem).  An implementation of such a problem will scale properly only on a supercomputer with high-bandwidth, low-latency interconnect.  Contrast this with embarrassingly parallel problems, implementations of which run efficiently even on systems with very poor interconnect (e.g. [farms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_farm)).

Notable example of a communication-intensive problem: solving `A x = b` where `A` is a large, dense matrix.  As a matter of fact, an implementation of the problem is used to compile the [TOP500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOP500) ranking.  It's a good benchmark, as it emphasizes both the computational power of individual CPUs *and* the quality of interconnect (due to intensity of communication).

In more practical terms, any mathematical model which solves a system of partial differential equations on a regular grid using discrete time stepping (think: weather forecasting, [in silico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_silico) crash tests), is parallelizable by [domain decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_decomposition_methods).  That means, each CPU takes care of a part of the grid, and at the end of each time step the CPUs exchange their results on region boundaries with "neighbour" CPUs.  These exchanges render this class of problems communication-intensive.

Comment: This answer deserves more emphasis.

Comment: ironically, top500 is widely dissed in the HPC community because it does *not* provide a good communication exercise.  blocking provides a too-effective speedup of matmul, for instance.  problems that merely do neighbor exchange are similarly fairly light communicators.  naive n-body gravity simulations would be an example of comm-intensive - FFTs aren't bad either, since higher-dimensional FFTs are often implemented using all-to-all.

Comment: @markhahn True. Another example (although not based on floating-point calculations): Graph500 benchmarks are very much focused on communication.

Answer (score 13):

Im having a hard time to not post this... cause I know it don't add anything to the discussion.. but for all southpark fans out there

"Super serial!"

Comment: Don't forget to include the lisp

Answer (score 12):

"Stubbornly serial"?

Answer (score 10):

The opposite of embarassingly parallel is [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), which says that some tasks cannot be parallel, and that the minimum time a perfectly parallel task will require is dictated by the purely sequential portion of that task.

Comment: Amdahl's law describes the limitation on *speed-up* from multiple processors, for an algorithm with a given level of parallelization.  I don't think it says anything directly about parallelizability per se.

Answer (score 9):

"standard examples" of sequential processes:

- making a baby: “Crash programs fail because they are based on theory that, with nine women pregnant, you can get a baby a month.” -- attributed to Werner von Braun
- calculating pi, e, sqrt(2), and other irrational numbers to millions of digits: most algorithms sequential
- navigation: to get from point A to point Z, you must first go through some intermediate points B, C, D, etc.
- Newton's method: you need each approximation in order to calculate the next, better approximation
- challenge-response authentication
- key strengthening
- hash chain
- Hashcash

Answer (score 5):

P-complete (but that's not known for sure yet).

Answer (score 5):

I use "Humiliatingly Sequential"

Paul

Answer (score 4):

If ever one should speculate what it would be like to have natural, incorrigibly sequential problems, try

***blissfully sequential***

to counter '*embarrassingly parallel*'.

Answer (score 2):

"Gladdengly Sequential"

Answer (score 2):

It all has to do with data dependencies.  Embarrassingly parallel problems are ones for which the solution is made up of many independent parts.  Problems with the opposite of this nature would be ones that have massive data dependencies, where there is little to nothing that can be done in parallel.  **Degeneratively dependent**?

Answer (score 2):

The term I've heard most often is "tightly-coupled", in that each process must interact and communicate often in order to share intermediate data. Basically, each process depends on others to complete their computation.

For example, matrix processing often involves sharing boundary values at the edges of each array partition.

This is in contrast to embarassingly parallel (or loosely-coupled) problems where each part of the problem is completely self-contained, and no (or very little) IPC is needed. Think master/worker parallelism.

Comment: This is actually the best answer so far, since it cuts to the core of the issue: it's all about the dataflow graph.

Answer (score 2):

Boastfully sequential.

Answer (score 2):

I've always preferred 'sadly sequential'  ala the partition step in quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

"Completely serial?"

It shouldn't really surprise you that scientists think more about what can be done than what cannot be done. Especially in this case, where the alternative to parallelizing is doing everything as one normally would.

Answer (score 0):

Completely non-parallelizable?
Pessimally parallelizable?

Answer (score 0):

The opposite is "disconcertingly serial".

Comment: How do you figure that out? Neither is it common usage nor does it make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

taking into acount that parallelism is the act of doing many jobs in the same time step t. the opposite could be time-sequential problems

Answer (score -1):

An example inherently sequential problem.
This is common in CAD packages and some kinds of engineering analysis.

Tree traversal with data dependencies between nodes.

Imagine traversing a graph and adding up weights of nodes.

You just can't parallelise it.

CAD software represents parts as a tree, and to render to object you have to traverse the tree.
For this reason, cad workstations use less cores and faster, rather than many cores.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: graph traversal is, of course, parallelizable.  the problem here is that the work-per-step is too trivial (summation), compared to the cost of following an edge (in serial or in parallel).

Answer (score -4):

You could of course, however I think that both 'names' are a non-issue.
From a functional programming perspective you could say that the 'annoyingly sequential' part is the smallest more or less independent part of an algorithm.

While the 'embarrassingly parallel' if not indeed taking into a parallel approach is bad coding practice.

Thus I don't see a point in given these things a name if good coding practice is always to brake up your solution into independent pieces, even if you at that moment don't take advantage of parallelism.

Comment: how is 'embarrassingly parallel' bad coding practice? It describes a set of problems, not the solution.

Comment: Plenty of algorithms are inherently embarrassingly parallel. An easy one would be the game of life's algorithm. You can do every node simultaneously.